# Reference request for differential graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I am interested in learning about differential graph theory or differential operators on graphs, something related to what [E. Bautista](https://mathoverflow.net/users/173461/e-bautista) introduced in his answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392391/differentiation-of-functions-over-graphs). Can one suggest a textbook in which such topics are discussed? (The quoted answer refers to some papers, but I prefer a book covering a comprehensive treatment of the topic.)